# Tracking Time variance through Impala Partitioning

Tags: hadoop, hive, cloudera, data-warehouse, impala

Could partitioning by a date be a feasible way to track time variance of data in a Big Data environment? My hope is to achieve something similar to the concept of slowly changing dimensions in RDBMS. Let's assume the following scenario to keep it simple:

---

### Scenario

I have a hadoop cluster with our data residing in hdfs, currently in .csv files. I also want to use Apache Impala as the query engine.
We have some customer data like this:

> Nr.,   Gender, Title,  firstname,  name,   birthday,   street, plz, city,  phone
>   1, Frau,   Dr.,    Jenny,  Hutch,  23.03.1924, Abcstr. 79, 97230,  Duggenfeld, 093 / 38700

Every day, new data will arrive via .csv (Lets just say every day a new, complete version of the customer data is delivered). The new data has to be integrated into our storage system.

---

### The Plan

The idea was, that I could enrich the customer data with a timestamp of its delivery:

> Nr.,   Gender, Title,  firstname,  name,   birthday,   street, plz, city,  phone, **deliverydate**
>   1, Frau,   Dr.,    Jenny,  Hutch,  23.03.1924, Abcstr. 79, 97230,  Duggenfeld, 093 / 38700, **20170814**

Then, when creating the corresponding impala table, i would just use the timestamp of delivery to partition the Table.
In theory, this would give us a full daily snapshot of the data that we could query against in the future.
This would not create the same table-structure as in SCD2 where we have a timespan of validity, but by querying over different days we could see when, for example, a name changed.

**Do you think this is a good use of partitioning or do I already have a flaw in my thoughts that i can't see at the moment?**
 There might also be deliveries in the future where the new data that comes daily is just a delta of changed/new values. This could be handled by joining the new data over the data from the last day to spot changes and new entries.

I already read some interesting posts on here:

- [What is the difference between partitioning and bucketing a table in Hive ?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19128940)
- [Slowly changing dimensions- SCD1 and SCD2 implementation in Hive](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37472146)
- [How does Impala supports Partitioning?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26484514)

And I also watched the *EDW 101 for Hadoop Professionals* Webinar by Cloudera, but they do not mention partitiong as a way to deal with time-variance.
I have very little practical experience with hadoop and Impala, so I appreciate every answer.

Comment: Voted to close, SO is not the right place for this. Being that said - **(1)** It seems that you don't understand how Hive partitions are defined **(2)** Your logic for the "last day" is false.

Comment: -SO is not the right place for this. How so? i mean i get it, i'm new and its no question about some source code snippet but could you elaborate? - (2) Your logic for the "last day" is false - Again, i am here to learn but just saying "its false" does not really add anything

Comment: "This site is all about getting answers. It's not a discussion forum. There's no chit-chat" https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Okay, if this came off as chit-chat and gets closed i will try to revise it.